# Heroku. Java. Unable to find resource. My deployed app can't find file in resource folder

Tags: java, spring, email, heroku, velocity

config file:

```
// import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
@Bean
public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
    final VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();

    velocityEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
    velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");

    return velocityEngine;
}
```

locally everything is fine but when I deploy my app to Heroku
I catch that exception:

```
velocityEngine.getTemplate("./templates/template_1.html");
```

Exception:

```
ResourceNotFoundException
Unable to find resource './templates/template_1.html'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `velocityEngine.getTemplate("templates/template_1.html")`, as an absolute/file system based path like `./templates/template_1.html` wouldn't exist after the application has been packaged into a jar file or docker image. You can find the sample app in [github](https://github.com/devatherock/spring-boot-demo/tree/velocity)